# Name for a circular data structure delivery system?

Tags: data-structures

Let's say I have a data structure, which is essentially a circularly linked list. The usage of this circularly linked list is to continuously be walked, and at each node, delivery the data at that node to consumers. Therefor, the more frequently the same thing appears in the circularly linked list, the more frequently it will be delivered to a consumer.

Is there a name for this data structure?

Comment: A circularly linked list.  What you DO with it is irrelevant to what data structure it is.

Comment: @ScottHunter I disagree with you. A queue or stack is often implemented with a linked list, but attaching behavior to it gives it a completely different meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circular queue, circular buffer, cyclic buffer or ring buffer. I think [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) is the most common name I've heard.

Answer (score 0):

Ringbuffer.